# Validate a String for ASCII characters

Tags: .net, character-encoding, ascii

I am writing a function that expects a byte array as input. This input array should represent a valid ASCII string.

I am trying to figure out a way to verify the above requirement. If it makes any difference the array should be 8 bytes long.

I have considered checking if each byte is inside the ASCII range, but doesn't work for chars that are multiple bytes.

I have also seen that .NET `Encoding.ASCII.getString()` can parse the bytes and returns `'?'` for any invalid characters. Is there a function that I can use to get a boolean indication validation?

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By ASCII, you mean lower 7 bits only?

Comment: I don't think ASCII has any chars that are multiple bytes.  Checking for ? does not really help as ? can also be the valid ASCII ?.

Comment: Ascii doesn't have any multiple byte chars but how do I know a byte is on it's own or part of a multibyte character from another charset?

Comment: You don't.  You cannot decode unless you know the encoding.

Comment: I'm not looking to decode. I simply want to determine if the bytes collection represents a valid ASCII string? Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: So you are not trying to decode.  Is a valid ASCII string and represents is not the same thing.

Comment: Maybe I just worded it badly then. Imagine the input is a byte array. If I was to convert that byte array back to a string using the ASCII scheme would it convert correctly? Surely this is a common problem?

Comment: What is the "common problem"?  Post code to reproduce this "common problem".

Answer (score 1):

If, by ASCII, you mean characters 0 – 127, you can validate it very simply:

```
if (bytes.All(b => b < 128))
```

If you mean one of the many 8-bit encodings, there are no invalid byte sequences.